# Copy matching filenames(pdf) from directory and a column in excel to a new directory in Python

Tags: python, file-handling, shutil

Compare files(pdf) in directory with list of names which are provided as a column in an excel csv and only keep those files in the directory which match or copy the new files to an existing directory, using python. How to go about doing that.

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: This removed all the pdf files from the directory. What I want is to match filenames with the column in csv and only keep those and delete the rest. Anyway to do that? Thanks

Comment: Mate, first of all you structured question incorrectly, did not put an effort in it at all and did not provide any sample code you created. So, learn most important things first: set the question clear and right. you did not say what names you have in csv file so I assumed it contains a list of names you want to remove from the dir. If you want to insert some files into dir_path directory then simply just change os.remove to e.g. shutil.copy and add os.remove at the end.

Comment: "What I want is to match filenames" which filenames you want to match? (which directory?) ...  "with the column in csv" what does this column contain? what file names? what directory? ...  "and only keep those" which files do you want to keep? ...  "and delete the rest." which files do you want to delete?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Answers in line: 1. There is only one column in excel which contains around 600 rows of pdf filenames. The same pdf filenames are present in my directory along with 300 more(total 900 pdf files). I want to filter my directory such that it only contains the 600 filenames which are present in the csv. Is it clear now?

Comment: this is what my code does: it removes all the files from dir_path that are not listed in the csv file

Comment: I tested it with foo.csv file containing A, b, c in first column rows 1,2,3 and files a.pdf, b.pdf, c.pdf in the my_dir directory. I run the code and it leaves a.pdf, b.pdf only

Comment: Surely. I have done the same. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dir_path = 'mydir'
file_path = 'foo.csv'

f = pd.read_csv(file_path, names=['A'])
ll1 = [os.remove(os.path.join(dir_path, x)) for x in os.listdir(dir_path) if x.replace('.pdf', '') not in f['A'].tolist()]
```

Comment: It works man. Thanks a lot. The only change I did was to remove the "if x.replace('.pdf', ' ')"  part with only 'if x''